# Global variable is inaccesible

Tags: javascript

I have this global variable "day". It contains the day(Monday,Tuesday etc) of the client. I coded it like this:

```
setInterval(update,1000);
function update(){
    let today= new Date();
    globalThis.day=today.getDay();
    let date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
}
```

I have made it global as you can see with `globalThis` but when I try to access it from another function,

```
window.onload=function(){
    if (day==6){
        console.log("Today is Sunday.");
    }
    else{
        console.log("Today isn't Sunday");
    }
}
```

microsoft edge gave me an error saying:
Uncaught ReferenceError: day is not defined
at window.onload
The ultimate goal here
is to access the variable "day" from inside the anonymous function.

Comment: replace it with `window.day`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis#browser_compatibility…?

Comment: `window.onload` runs before `update` from `setInterval`.

Comment: One thing to note though, If you are using **strict mode**, accessing `day` variable from outside the function without first calling the function would through an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Multiple errors in your code:*

1. Your `window.onload` function runs before `update()` which is called inside `setInterval()`.
2. Your global object is `globalThis` and `day` is its property. You can access the latter like this: `globalThis.day`.

Comment: I tried removing `window.onload` and just `console.log(globalThis.day)` .It kind of worked but the output for some reason was "undefined"

Comment: It is undefined because your `update()` function that is called by `setInterval()` has not been called yet.

Comment: I made the console log `globalThis.day` after a few seconds and it worked. Thanks.